# Can't edit sources.list as root

Tags: debian, permissions, root

I cannot edit/move/delete the `sources.list` file, despite being root. When I do `ls -la /etc/apt` it reports this:

```
root@nibelung:~# ls -la /etc/apt/
total 356
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root   4096 Feb 28 21:30 .
drwxrwxr-x 100 root root   4096 Feb 28 01:29 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     98 Aug 24  2013 apt.conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Feb 27 14:04 apt.conf.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    123 Feb 28 01:52 preferences
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Feb 27 21:01 preferences.d
-rw-------   1 root root      0 Aug 24  2013 secring.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    878 Jan 24 19:30 sources.list
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      0 Sep 27 02:00 sources.list~
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    878 Feb 28 21:30 sources.list.bk
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Feb 27 21:01 sources.list.d
-rw-------   1 root root   1200 Jan 24 15:03 trustdb.gpg
-rw-------   1 root root 158664 Jan 24 15:03 trusted.gpg
-rw-------   1 root root 158664 Jan 24 15:03 trusted.gpg~
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Apr 15  2011 trusted.gpg.d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to edit it, what happens? What error do you get?

Things to look at first:

- Is the filesystem mounted read-only? (check `mount`)
- Is the file immutable? (check `lsattr sources.list`; if it's set `+i`, `chattr -i sources.list`)

Comment: Out of curiosity, which was it; the filesystem or immutability?